# How to change higlight color if use statement is missing in phpstorm?

Tags: configuration, phpstorm

I am using phpstorm. If a class is not imported properly via its use statement, I get a rather low-contrast indication, brown on gray background.

As this is a serious error I want to change that specific color into something more drastic. How to change that color?

A picture speaks more than words::

[image: Low contrast example of missing use statement]

I am talking about the backgroud of `getCount`-method and the `AssetRepository` class usage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can **change color** here: `Settings | Editor | Colors &  Fonts | General | Warning` (this is IDE-wide setting and will affect ALL projects)

**Alternatively** -- **change severity** from "Warning" to "Error" (or introduce your own with your own colors) in `Settings | Inspections | PHP | Undefined | Undefined method` (this is project-level setting so it could be different from project to project).